# How to Display Formatted Text From HTML in Tapestry

Tags: html, tapestry

In my TextArea, I'm using CKEditor as a mixins, and all changes, include the formatting goes to my DB. How to display it as formatted text, which means if HTML is `<b>My Name</b> is <i>Hobas</i>` will displayed as **My Name** is *Hobas*. I've tried `JSoup` but it looks like that lib doesn't support this job.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OutputRaw component in your template (.Tml) file:

See http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/OutputRaw.html